# Update URL parameter with javascript, without ruining the history?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, hash

I'm looking for a way to update the url in the status bar..
I have a gallery, and when you click your way through the gallery I want the image ID to show up in the URL, so that the user can link directly to the image..

I've read about using hash and so. but as far as I've tried it, that "ruins" the history.
If I click the back-button in my browser the previous image would be shown.

Is it possible to add or update a URL parameter, without ruining the history?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it simply this way, when switching to images, add a hash to the url, for example:

```
location+='#image-'+image_id
```

your location will become

```
http://example.org/images/#image-3
```

instead of the initial

```
http://example.org/images/
```

and onload, check if `location.hash` is not empty, and matches with `^image-(\d+)$` *(regular expression pattern)*, if it matches, do the usual thing you'd have done if a user clicks on image with id `(\d+)`.

To preserve history, use [reallysimplehistory](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/).

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was possible for the gallery to show the ID and show the right picture when typing in the picture ID. I'm using Jquery Cycle, and it's a thread over at the jquery forum about this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-plugin-trying-to-achieve-permalinks-while-using-paging - I'll check out the reallysimplehistory-library! Thanks! ;D

Answer (score 3):

Use [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#replace) to replace the current location:

> Replace the current document with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the `assign()` method is that after using `replace()` the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

Comment: Hum, I tried that, but it reloaded the page, and I don't want that either.. XD Thanks anyway (:

Comment: @guzh: You can only change the URI fragment without reloading.

Comment: hum, okey. I found out I'd use hash instead, it's easier (: Thanks for your help, I'll look into your solution a bit further!